# How to identify different sections of a webpage

Tags: php, jquery, domparser

I am working on a project **where user enters the url of his  website and it will be automatically converted to a mobile website**. For that I have used PHP Mobilizer and Simple HTML DOM Parser. But I want to do it another way as these parsers are not giving me expected output. I want to identify the different sections of the webpage of the given url.

> For example, I want to identify the section which contains the word
>   "logo" (with regex) and initially mark it at logo section. I think in this way, I can spot other sections (e.g. content,footer etc),too.

I am new in PHP and JQuery, hence if someone gives a tiny clue about how to do that, it will be of great help. I hope this is possible in PHP. Thanks.

Comment: What if the user's provided site have no **logo** or **footer**?

Comment: What if the term "logo" is included in a part of the site other than the header/logo section? I think you may be asking for trouble with a script like this.

Comment: I do know that sections of all websites are most of the time supposed to have different names and positions. It is nowhere mandatory that a dev must term the logo with a "something-logo" or that kind. But for a start, let's assume there's an image inside a div which has been named as "abc-logo" or "logo" or "mylogo". Now how can I spot that very part? Thanks for quick reply, though.